# Add Providers to Linux SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, sql-server-linux

I want add a new linked server in my SQL Server (15.0.4261.1) running on Linux Red Hat Enterprise 8.6, before I add a linked server to other SQL Server database, but now when I want add a linked server to other  I can't.

I check my SQL Server on linux and I found that I not had any provider in the section "Server Objects".

My question is: how to add providers in SQL Server on Linux?

Any other information is very much appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, and for these is it compatible?

Answer (score 0):

> Linked Servers to data sources other than SQL Server

Are not supported on Linux.

[SQL Server on Linux - Unsupported features & services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2019?view=sql-server-ver16#Unsupported)

Comment: Thank you, and for these is it compatible? -ADsDSOObject
-MSDAOSP  
-MSDASQL
-MSIDXSto
-MSOLAP  
-SQLNCLI10
-SQLOLEDB

Comment: SQL Server 2019+ uses MSOLEDBSQL for SQL Server linked server connections.  Earlier versions used SQLNCLI11.  No other Linked Server providers are supported, and there's no supported way to install additional OleDb provider for SQL Server on Linux.